# Spy function with params by Sinon.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon, typeorm

I'm trying to write some unit tests of code that uses typeorm without hitting the DB.
And I'm using sinon for spy/stub/mock.
This is my function.

```js
  async updateDoingToFailedWithLock(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.manager
      .getRepository(Report)
      .createQueryBuilder("report")
      .useTransaction(true)
      .setLock("pessimistic_write")
      .update(Report)
      .set({ status: ReportStatus.FAILED })
      .where(`(status = "doing")`)
      .execute();
  }
```

I already wrote a fake test to make sure `execute()` is called by using spy function. 
But I want to test the params of these functions `createQueryBuilder`..., the sure the params are correct. 
I took a look at sinon document and it seems like sinon support test params by this API: `spy().withArgs(arg1, arg2...)`.

But I'm not sure how to spy my function correctly.

```js
describe("updateDoingToFailedWithLock()", (): void => {
    let sandbox: Sinon.SinonSandbox;

    beforeEach(() => (sandbox = Sinon.createSandbox()));
    afterEach(() => sandbox.restore);

    it("should be success", async (): Promise<void> => {
      const fakeManager = {
        getRepository: () => {
          return fakeManager;
        },
        createQueryBuilder: () => {
          return fakeManager;
        },
        useTransaction: () => {
          return fakeManager;
        },
        setLock: () => {
          return fakeManager;
        },
        update: () => {
          return fakeManager;
        },
        set: () => {
          return fakeManager;
        },
        where: () => {
          return fakeManager;
        },
        execute: () => {},
      };
      const fakeQueryRunner = {
        manager: fakeManager,
      };
      const connection = new typeorm.Connection({ type: "mysql" });
      const reportService = new ReportService();
      sandbox.stub(connection, "createQueryRunner").callsFake((): any => {
        return fakeQueryRunner;
      });

      const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
      const spy = sandbox.spy(fakeManager, "execute");

      reportService.updateDoingToFailedWithLock(queryRunner);
      expect(spy.calledOnce).be.true;
    });
  });
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code and there's something can be improved:

- Use `returnsThis()` to replace `return fakeManager`
- Don't forget `await` when calling `updateDoingToFailedWithLock`

```
describe("updateDoingToFailedWithLock()", (): void => {
  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;

  beforeEach(() => (sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()));
  afterEach(() => sandbox.restore);

  it("should be success", async (): Promise<void> => {

    // using returnsThis()
    const fakeManager = {
      getRepository: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      createQueryBuilder: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      useTransaction: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      setLock: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      update: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      set: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      where: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
      execute: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),      
    }

    const fakeQueryRunner = {
      manager: fakeManager,
    };

    const reportService = new ReportService();

    // having await here is important
    await reportService.updateDoingToFailedWithLock(fakeQueryRunner);


    expect(fakeManager.execute.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(fakeManager.createQueryBuilder.calledWith('report')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it seems good but when I run test, I got this problem: 
`TypeError: queryRunner.manager.getRepository(...).createQueryBuilder(...).useTransaction(...).setLock(...).update(...).set(...).where(...).andWhere is not a function`

Comment: seems you added `andWhere` which doesn't exist in code example of the question. To solve the error, we could add `andWhere: sandbox.stub().returnsThis()` after `where` line